# onclick in loop references only last element in loop

Tags: jquery, loops, jquery-mobile, associative-array

This is my code:

```
var $coursesList = $("#vakkenList");;
for (var course in lessons) {
    var $courseLi = $("<li/>", {
        "data-icon": "arrow-l",
            "data-iconpos": "left"
    });
    var $courseA = $("<a/>").append(course);
    $courseLi.append($courseA);
    $courseLi.click(function (e) {
        alert("click " + course);
        $("#AddLessonForm_vak").val(course);
        $("#gridItemDetailPanel2").panel("close");
        $("#gridItemDetailPanel").panel("open"); //TODO al open
    });
    $coursesList.append($courseLi);
};
$coursesList.listview("refresh");
```

When I do an onclick on the 'li' element it alerts the lasts course. In the html the correct course is appended. But something goes wrong with the reference in the onclick.
What do I do wrong?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops.3A_A_common_mistake

Comment: I too think this is a closure issue, try to create a fiddle so that you can get more answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don´t have a problem with the click events

You problem is with the var course.

When the loop finish your var course has the last course.

You need get the value from the li

```
$courseLi.click(function(e){
            var realCourse = $(this).find("a").html();
            alert("click "+ realCourse );
            $("#AddLessonForm_vak").val(realCourse);
            $("#gridItemDetailPanel2").panel( "close");
            $( "#gridItemDetailPanel" ).panel( "open"); //TODO al open
        });
```